# Symfony2.8->3.0: Request format override method

Tags: php, symfony

When I updated from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.0, the code below did not work as intended. When you press "csv output", `&_format=csv` is passed to the url and the page is redirected.
Originally, it will move to download the csv file.
Looking at the documentation, it seems that the specs have changed between 2.8 and 3.0, but there seems to be no mention of how to change them.
How should I change it?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/routing.html

Controller

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html') {
            // At the time of html output
        } elseif ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'csv') {
            // At the time of csv output
            // Set file name, no pagination
            $request->attributes->set('filename', 'post_article.csv');
        }
```

index.html.twig

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="_format" value="csv">
        <i class="icon-download"></i> CSV output
    </button>
```

index.csv.twig

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% if searchForm.content.vars.data -%}
    content,{{ searchForm.content.vars.data }}
{% endif %}
…
{% endautoescape %}
```

CsvListener

```php
class CsvResponseListener
{
    /**
     * kernel.response Set the response at the time of CSV output in the event
     */
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        // Set the response at the time of CSV output in the event
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() === 'csv' && $response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Convert response body to CRLF, SJIS-WIN
            $content = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $response->getContent());
            $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'SJIS-WIN', 'UTF-8');
            $response->setContent($content);

            // Get the file name
            $filename = $request->attributes->get('filename', 'download.csv');

            // Set header for file download
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Length', strlen(bin2hex($content)) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```yaml
    app.listener.csvResponseListener:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\CsvResponseListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Comment: What does 'page is redirected' mean?  The index action is never called?  You currently have Method("GET") which has been replaced at some point but assuming it still works then only GET requests will be processed.  Typically you need _format as part of your route's url.  Maybe take a look at the [example](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/routing.html).

Comment: @Cerad As you said, the index action is being called. I tried changing ```"/"``` to ```"/{_format}"```, but the result was the same. The documentation has routing set as ```"/{title}.{_format}"```, but I don't know what to set for title.

Comment: Looks like you got it working.  Might want to start removing the Method annotation as well per the examples.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you. It seems that some of the different versions of the code were pasted. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add the slug `{_format}` to the route. If you have no other routes that will match `'/html'` or `'/csv'` then you should be able to just safely add the slug right in there:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_format}", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
```

Then on the front-end, you will need to add some javascript to change the action of the form to `'/csv'` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to move it safely.
Added ```<a class="a_btn" href="{{path('app_post_index', {'_format':'csv'})}}"> output </a>``` to twig.